# Invalid Group SID returned for context user identity in asp.net mvc and web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using the User's identity to get all the Group's Sids associated with the that user but

when calling the following in either asp.net mvc or web api:

```
var identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
```

And using the following to get the Groups' SIDs

```
var groupSids = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity)
    .Claims
    .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GroupSid)
    .Select(c => c.Value);
```

It includes (local) groups the user is not part of.

I'm going to check other methods in a second but I just don't understand why it's returning me local group SIDs from my machine and I've specifically removed myself from them to test this but to no avail.

Any ideas why? Am I using this incorrectly?

Thanks.

**UPDATE-1:**

I'm confused. When I call my Web API via Postman and authenticate my AD user via NTML, it returns the correct data.

When I'm in my asp.net mvc app and it calls my Web API, I can see that the 'HttpContext.Current.User.Identity' is set to my AD user but it contains different SIDs as when called via Postman.

Why??

Comment: What do you store in this `ClaimTypes.GroupSid` claim?

Comment: It's a build-in constant i.e. //
        // Summary:
        //     The URI for a claim that specifies the SID for the group of an entity, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid.
        public const string GroupSid = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid";

Comment: may be try saving user roles to your custom claim in comma separated string format. and access that when you need it, split it by comma to get the list.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. the linq query above returns me all the SIDs associated with my user. The problem is that it is returning SIDs representing groups I'm no longer part off and my question is why?